# PMCMD Command to get session statistics Informatica

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to use pmcmd command to get session statistics. I have updated the .bash_profile and logged in to the pmcmd path. However, I'm not able to connect to the integration service through pmcmd. I need to create a script which can be scheduled to run daily to get the session statistics from specific informatica folder.

command I'm using to first connect to pmcmd:

pmcmd> connect -sv  "Integration_EMEA_ETL_12C"  -d  Domain_gxxxxxx18 -u 12xxxx89 -p Kxxxx@2020!

ERROR: Failed to authenticate login. [CCM_10821] [CCM_10821] Authentication failed.

here I'm using my personal id and password which i use to login to informatica and UNIX. And if I have to create a generic script should i be using infaadmin id ?

let me know if any idea on this issue.

Comment: you need to use infa admin id. if you have admin access then probably you can but you can surely use admin id. And then you can use pmpasswd utility to encrypt your password later in Prod